# SQL Server Resource Pool and Workload Groups

Tags: sql-server, resource-governor

Below is the scenario:

Scenario 1:
I got two workload groups assigned **in the same resource pool** with MAX CPU 20%. In the event of CPU bottleneck, the limit will come into effect with 10% each workload group?

Scenario 2:
I got two workload groups assigned with **two different resource pool** with MAX CPU 10% each. In the event of CPU bottleneck, each resource pool/workload group will get 10% each?

Is it both scenario will get the same resource allocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those two scenarios will result in the same resource allocation - in theory.

In scenario 1, if there is CPU pressure, the two workloads running in the "20% resource pool" will *share* that CPU "equally."  How equally they are able to share the 20% can depend on a lot of things that are workload specific, given how SQL Server's scheduling algorithms work.

In scenario 2, if there is CPU pressure, the two workloads running in the "10% resource pool"s will each get a minimum of 10% of CPU time.

You have a better chance of a "fair" split of CPU in scenario 2, but scenario 1 could work depending on your specific workload.

Comment: Hi Josh, if i got one more scenario: multiple databases in the same workload group and assigned to the same resource pool (let say 20% max CPU), those databases will share the 20% equally as similarly to your answer on scenario 1? thanks!

Comment: @Yong Interesting question!  Workload groups are bound to sessions, not databases.  So the behavior will be exactly the same as #1.  Resource Governor doesn't care that one session is accessing `DatabaseA` and the other is accessing `DatabaseB`.